# for loop not working when it should be looping consistently

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
async def helper():
a = "SELECT username FROM stoccssss"
cursor.execute(a)
people = cursor.fetchall()
for x in people:
    cursor.execute("SELECT stock_selected FROM stoccssss WHERE username=%s", (x))
    thingy = cursor.fetchall()
    balls = ' '.join(map(str, thingy))
    stockthingy = str(balls).replace('[', '')
    stockthingy1 = str(stockthingy).replace(']', '')
    stockthingy2 = str(stockthingy1).replace('(', '')
    stockthingy3 = str(stockthingy2).replace(')', '')
    stockthingy4 = str(stockthingy3).replace("'", '')
    stockthingy5 = str(stockthingy4).replace(",", "")
    stockTicker = yf.Ticker(stockthingy5.upper())
    hmm = stockTicker.history(period='5m')
    hmm = hmm.reset_index()
    test = str(hmm['High']).split()
    price = str(test[1])
    cursor.execute("SELECT money_amount FROM stoccssss WHERE username=%s", (x))
    moneycap = cursor.fetchone()
    moneycap = str(moneycap).replace('(', '')
    moneycap = str(moneycap).replace(')', '')
    moneycap = str(moneycap).replace(',', '')

    if moneycap < price:
        cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM stoccssss WHERE username=%s", (x))
        user = cursor.fetchone()
        user = str(user).replace('(', '')
        user = str(user).replace(')', '')
        user = str(user).replace(',', '')
        user = str(user).replace("'", '')
        user = client.get_user(int(user))
        await user.send("YOUR STOCK HAS SURPASSED YOUR PRICE OF " + str(moneycap) + " POG")
        return


    else:
        cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM stoccssss WHERE username=%s", (x))
        user = cursor.fetchone()
        user = str(user).replace('(', '')
        user = str(user).replace(')', '')
        user = str(user).replace(',', '')
        user = str(user).replace("'", '')
        user = client.get_user(int(user))
        await user.send("YOUR STOCK HAS GONE LOWER THAN YOUR PRICE OF " + str(moneycap) + " POG")
        return

await asyncio.sleep(5)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("running")
    await helper()
```

The code is meant to dm someone whenever the stock is above or under a price, but for some reason the code only runs once and never again

anyone knows what's going on here?

adding text here because it asks me for more details but I don't know what else to say so ignore this last row of text

yes the code is indented properly, stackoverflow messed it up

Comment: None of your `helper()` code is indented

Comment: @yuuuu it actually is mb, wrote it wrong here

Comment: Why do you think that it "should be looping consistently"?

Comment: @DeepSpace is right.  You run through all the people once, and then you return, and the party's over.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put helper() in a loop, just doing

```py
while True:
  helper()
```

should do the trick.